# Event to play mp3 file in specific time when app closed or in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an application for Muslims prayer alert in IOS  ,

Iam already playing mp3 file by using when i click a button

and this is my code

```
super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapSound = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("mp", withExtension: "mp3")

        self.soundFileURLRef = tapSound

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURLRef)
        } catch _ {
            player = nil
        }
        player?.delegate = self
        player?.prepareToPlay()
    }

    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSLog("started playing")
        player?.play()
    }


    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        //
        NSLog("finished playing")
    }
```

and it's working perfeclty

Now I am looking for a way to play mp3 file in specific time like

> when time is  12:00 AM Play the mp3 file

even the application is closed

any suggestion how to make that in IOS ?

Thanks for help

Comment: You will want to schedule local notification, with custom sound.

Comment: what about notifications sound limit ? my audio file like 2 - 3 minutes

Comment: hey did you get any solution?

Comment: Yes just used LocationNotification

Comment: @Hi Muhammed. I need you help

Comment: @Muhammed mind sharing how you went about solving please for your app? It would be a great help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule events like this, you can use [Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html). It's how [all (that I know of) alarm clock apps](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/) alert you **when the app isn't open**. Local notifications, however, only allow you to play a 30 sec (max) sound clip that you have bundled with your application.

Currently there is no way to have your app play music as a background service unless it's currently open (or was open when you locked the screen if you opt out of multitasking... see the above link).

The built-in alarm clock app is allowed to do this, however, because it is using a private API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but my file like 2 / 3 mintues (min)

Comment: right, so as I write: it is not possible to do what you're asking. take a look at the link I provided that discusses how alarm clock apps work.

Comment: alright thanks for help  :) 

i guess i will use local notifications

Comment: from what I've looked into and observed, you can fire a local notification and then have the mp3 set to play automatically (if they interact with the notification) in `application:shouldHandleLocalNotification:`. Perhaps the local notification can be set to go off 5 minutes before the scheduled time, so the user is prompted to have the app open. That way you could avoid small delays in the local notifications. It's unfortunate that Apple does not allow for their clock API to be used :(

Answer (score 0):

Local Notifications work as suggested here but you should keep in mind that there is no 100% guarantee the notification will be fired precisely when you schedule them. Depending on the workload, the OS can delay it a little while (it could change from seconds to minutes). Just wanted to point that out since prayer times are very precise ;)

Comment: Thanks for the notice :)